# Compare the contents of a file one by one

Tags: shell

I am completely new to shell scripting. So please help me in solving this issue.

I have a file c1.txt which contains

```
List of devices attached 
0000000000000000    device
1234567891234567    device
```

I need to compare the above contents with a subset of device list using loop.

eg:

```
v=c1.txt
while [$v!=0]
  if ($v==1234567891234567 or 1234567891234566 or 12345678912345645)
    echo "XXX device"
  else
    echo "YYY device"
```

I am wrong with the syntax but i have given the logical flow of my expectation.
Kindly help me out in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep`.  For example,

```
grep -E '1234567891234567|1234567891234566|12345678912345645' c1.txt
```

would list devices matching `1234567891234567`, `1234567891234566`, or `12345678912345645` in the file `c1.txt`.

If you want to list the *devices* that don't match in the input, you could supply the `-v` option to `grep`:

```
grep -Ev '1234567891234567|1234567891234566|12345678912345645' c1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
while read device name; do
    case $device in
      1234567891234567 | 1234567891234566 | 12345678912345645)
        echo "XXX device" ;;
      *)
        echo "YYY device" ;;
    esac
done <c1.txt
```